# URL Redirects not showing, do I need to refresh the indices?

Tags: magento-enterprise, category, url-rewrite, indexing

We are running Magento Enterprise edition and have multiple sites for various countries, however some of the categories we have created aren't working (the clean URL we expect them to work on isn't).

So I've checked the URL redirects and these haven't automatically been created. I believe this may be due to us never having re-indexed the Category URL Rewrites or the URL Redirects indices, would refreshing these automatically create the clean URL redirects and solve our problem?

Comment: Will, what EE version do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Refresh you index in Configuration > Index Management